# Is there a way to determine which columns are editable at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have several `DataGrids` all using a common event handler: `DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown`.

It's purpose is to look for tab key events and insert a new row when the user tabs off the last edit cell of the last row. The grids have several columns of which only a couple are editable.

Currently, what I have is shown below. It uses `grid.CurrentCell.Column.Header.ToString() == "myColumnHeaderName"`. myColumnHeaderName only works for one grid, as the other grids do not have that column.

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.Key == Key.Tab && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None )
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        if ( grid.SelectedIndex == grid.Items.Count - 1 ) // last row
        {
            if ( grid.CurrentCell.Column.Header.ToString() == "myColumnName" )
            {
                grid.CommitEdit();
                AppendToGrid( grid );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Column has the `IsReadOnly` Property, so just check

```
if (!grid.CurrentCell.Column.IsReadOnly)
```